# Linux service account management

Tags: linux, active-directory, user-accounts

We use Windows Active Directory for account management. As a security policy, we need to change password for service accounts at least every six months. What we are experiencing is, when we change the password on AD, the application breaks before we get to change the password on servers where the account is being used. I was wondering if any of you experienced this issue. How did you resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: This could use some clarification... for example, what does Linux have to do with it?  Also, what's the problem here?  You update your AD passwords at the same time as you update the local servers/services.

Answer (score 1):

Use correctly configured cache daemon on Linux server side.

SSSD works quite good with Active Directory.

Here is the link to RHEL Guide:

[RHEL6 AD INTEGRATION AND SSSD GUIDE](http://www.redhat.com/rhecm/rest-rhecm/jcr/repository/collaboration/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/ae40084d0a052601783f1ea42715cdef/26/jcr:frozenNode/rh:resourceFile)